# ASP.NET MVC 4 + Entity Framework 6 + SQL Compact Edition 4.0 deployment no install

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6

Im trying to deploy a basic MVC 4 app that uses Entity Framework 6 (Code First) and SQL Compact 4.0
on a clean install of windows 7 with iis installed (mvc 4 and sql compact 4.0 is not installed).

I got the following nuget packages installed on the db project:

- EntityFramework (Version 6.0.0-alpha2)
- EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact (Version 6.0.0-alpha2)
- Microsoft.AspNet.Providers (Version 1.2)
- Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core (Version 1.2)
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact (Version 4.0.8876.1)

In web.config i got the following config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="[Name]" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|[FileName].sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>  

......................

<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
     <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
     </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Bin folder (sql ce files are in amd64 and x86 folder:

- [amd64]
- [x86]
- Antlr3.Runtime.dll
- DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll
- DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll
- DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.dll
- DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll
- DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll
- DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll
- EntityFramework.dll
- EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
- EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml
- EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.dll
- EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.xml
- EntityFramework.xml
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll
- Newtonsoft.Json.dll
- ShipMedProto.DB.dll
- ShipMedProto.DB.pdb
- ShipMedProto.Web.dll
- ShipMedProto.Web.pdb
- System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
- System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
- System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
- System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll
- System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
- System.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Http.dll
- System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll
- System.Web.Mvc.dll
- System.Web.Optimization.dll
- System.Web.Providers.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
- WebActivatorEx.dll
- WebGrease.dll
- WebMatrix.Data.dll
- WebMatrix.WebData.dll

When I deploy to the clean machine I get the following error message:

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

On my dev machine it is working fine. (I got sql ce installed)

Any clue what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure all the required binaries are deployed to the bin folder

Comment: I have ensuered that. Do you know if the sqlce dlls should be placed in bin -> x86 folder

Comment: Yes, the x86 DLLs in the bin/x86 folder and the x64 dlls in the bin/AMD64 folder. You also need a dbProviders section, see my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: The dbProviders config solved my problem. Thank you @ErikEJ !

Answer (score 5):

I think what you really want to do is manage the NuGet packages such that you add SqlServerCompact support for EntityFramework. Just right click your references and Manager NuGet packages. Then in the dialog do a search for SqlServerCompact. You SHOULD see this:

[image]

Adding this should add the equivalent strings that were in the answer above. I ended up with this in the web.config (or app.config if you're doing an app)

```
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
        </providers>   
</entityFramework>   
<system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
          <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
          <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </DbProviderFactories>   
</system.data>
```

Sorry, I'm about a year late but hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are deploying to a server without SQL CE installed, you also need to deploy the native binaries. Simplest way is to add a post-build step to copy these from the NuGet package NativeBinaries folder

Answer (score 1):

This is a configuration I am using that works.

I've added the projects from NuGet:
EntityFramework (6.0.1)
EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact (6.0.1)
Microsoft Sql Server Compact Edition (4.0.8876.1).  Note, I do not have this assembly flagged to copy local.

I've added the files from the SQLCE 4 private install folders

And then I set my config as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="SecureSend.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
    <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin"/>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalUserContext" connectionString="Data Source=c:\temp\LocalUserDataStore.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```